# why exec('java -jar file.jar') dont work on browser but works on command line?

Tags: java, php, linux, apache, executable-jar

I try to run an jar from an php file like this:

```
exec("java -jar /home/florinbuda/NetBeansProjects/monkey1/dist/monkey1.jar", $result);          
print_r($result);
```

and IT WORKS if I run it from command line like:

```
$ php runner.php
```

but it doesn't work if I try to load it via http-localhost-server/runner.php the page just keeps loading forever without giving any error..

In the .jar file I added a simple test to now if the jar is even started to work

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new File("/home/florinbuda/Desktop/xxx").mkdir();
```

and as you can guess - when I call http-localhost-server/runner.php  the jar is not even started to be executed...

It's a problem of rights?  What suggestions do you have?

Comment: It's probably rights, the apache user or whatever usually has very limited rights to make hacking more difficult

Comment: Perhaps try `exec("whoami", $result)` and see if that user has rights to the file and directory you're trying to reach.

Comment: good ideea!
I get different results for console and browser
`florinbuda` and `www-data`. Now is a matter of how to give www-data rights to run java?

Comment: Don't forget rights to /home/florinbuda/NetBeansProjects/monkey1/dist/monkey1.jar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the problem of permission.

You should chmod the parent folder of .jar file.

```
chmod 755 -R /home/florinbuda/NetBeansProjects/monkey1/dist/
```

**EDIT:** And then your script should look like this:

```
exec("PATH_TO/java -jar /home/florinbuda/NetBeansProjects/monkey1/dist/monkey1.jar");
```

Comment: yes it worked in a final, but I also had to chmod the target directory

Answer (score 0):

The environment variables in bash aren't the same in exec(). Use the full path for java bin at least. You could also try just to run /path/to/java to see the normal output is working.