# Trying to run a jar from PHP

Tags: php, jar

After reading some of the posts in this website related to exactly the same issue I've got, I found that none of them were giving me a successful result:

[How to run a jar from a web server using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17596237/how-to-run-a-jar-from-a-web-server-using-php)

[Run Java class file from PHP script on a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2128619/run-java-class-file-from-php-script-on-a-website)

[why exec('java -jar file.jar') dont work on browser but works on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13368155/why-execjava-jar-file-jar-dont-work-on-browser-but-works-on-command-line)

I'm using a Windows Server 2008 R2 datacenter, 64 bits, it's an EC2 instance from AWS.
The command that I use to run my jar in a php file is exec, which works for any phyton script and normal .exe programs. But when it comes to a jar, it does nothing.

This is my code (my jar needs 5 parameters):

```
$script = "java -jar scripts/IDW.jar 5 none 2 values_grid values";      
$result = exec($script, $output);
if ($result) {
    print_r($output);           
}
else {
    echo "Failed";
}
echo "<br/>Result: ". $result;
```

The result I have is:

```
Failed
Result:
```

When I run the jar on console, it runs perfectly, but not from PHP, which means I am passing the right parameter values at the above Php code.

Java version: 1.7.0_51 and PHP version: 5.4.26

I would highly appreciate any comments on this.

Comment: Try to adjust the path to `java`, e.g `whereis java`.

Comment: And what is inside `$output`?

Comment: @d3l The path is adjusted already to java. The final part of it is: 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;'. Also my 'Java environment variable' is set to 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre7';

Comment: @Tyralcori I added a new line to show the $output and it is: 1, although my jar file should return a different output, actually, it should be many lines...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a straight answer, but if calling java from Php does not work under any circumstances, you can also run jar files from Python scripts. I mean Php --> Python --> jar.

Calling Python scripts from Php always works for me.

This post helped me in the past:

[Python: How can I execute a jar file through a python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372592/python-how-can-execute-a-jar-file-through-a-python-script)

Answer (score 1):

You can check with  shell_exec, system() and other function pctl function as well. These functions might be disabled, so before executing check them or you can use this as well

```
function execInBackground($cmd) { 
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
        pclose(popen("start /B ". $cmd, "r"));  
    } 
    else { 
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
    } 
}
```

More detail found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Comment: Hi @Hrishikesh, I tried your code and it seems unstoppable. It never comes back. It's always waiting and I think it gets stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like this:

```
//REPLACE THIS PATH WITH THE REAL JAVA PATH
$handle = popen(`"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\jre7\\bin\\java.exe arguments"`, "r"));
//You can read with $read = fread($handle, 2096)
pclose($handle);
```

exec will not work on Windows (for "external" executables) and in most cases you'll have to provide the full path to Java.