# How to run jar file or java method from an html page?

Tags: javascript, java, html

i'm trying to do a web page that shows query results from a database on charts.

I have a java project who makes lot of processes and stores filtered information from web pages (web crawling) into the database.

I need to implement a button on my web page that update the database by running the java program.

I don't know if this is possible by running an specific method or if i have to run the jar file of the project.

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to run a jar from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25231334/trying-to-run-a-jar-from-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, you cannot do it directly.

Long answer:
You need to create a web application running on a server to serve your web page and connect it to your database.
Other option if you want to run everything locally is to create a java application (java fx I mean)